# Unity Video Player support for Hololens

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, hololens-emulator

When i try to run video player in Unity for Hololens, the app crashes (memory overflow). Is there a way to run video player in Hololens.

update:
'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'c:\data\Programs\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0_1.0.23819.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\mscorlib.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User\entrypoint\VideoPlayer.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User\System.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User\WinMetadata\Windows.winmd'. Module was built without symbols.
'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User\UnityPlayer.winmd'. Module was built without symbols.
'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User\WinRTBridge.winmd'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User\BridgeInterface.winmd'. Module was built without symbols.
'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User\System.Collections.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User\UnityEngine.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User\Assembly-CSharp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User\UnityEngine.Networking.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User\UnityEngine.HoloLens.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User\UnityEngine.UI.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User\System.IO.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User\System.Net.Primitives.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User\System.Private.Networking.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User\System.Reflection.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User\System.Threading.Tasks.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User\System.Private.Uri.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User\System.Text.Encoding.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User\UnityEngine.VR.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User\System.Threading.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Module information:
 Built with Compiler Ver '190023918'
 Built from '5.6/release' branch
 Version is '5.6.0b3 (358ff4ed3952)'
 Debug build
 Application type 'D3D11'
 Used 'UWP'

OS 'Windows 10 (10.0.14393)'

PlayerConnection initialized from C:/Data/Users/DefaultAccount/AppData/Local/DevelopmentFiles/VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User/Data (debug = 0)

PlayerConnection initialized network socket : 0.0.0.0 55348

Multi-casting "[IP] 172.16.80.2 [Port] 55348 [Flags] 2 [Guid] 3675464893 [EditorId] 4294967295 [Version] 1048832 [Id] MetroPlayerX86(HoloLens-SP0ED) [Debug] 0" to [225.0.0.222:54997]...

Started listening to [0.0.0.0:55348]

GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1

Direct3D:

```
Version:  Direct3D 11.0 [level 11.1]

Renderer: Microsoft RemoteFX Graphics Device - WDDM (ID=0x2c1)

Vendor:   Microsoft

VRAM:     639 MB
```

Initialize engine version: 5.6.0b3 (358ff4ed3952)

'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User\UnityEngineProxy.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User\System.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VideoPlayer.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VideoPlayerVS.Debug_x86.Web_User\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Logical Screen DPI is 144.00.

The following GlobalManagers were stripped from the build (Either because they're not used or not supported on this platform):
  NetworkManager
  MasterServerInterface
  UnityAdsManager
  ClusterInputManager
  UnityAnalyticsManager
  CrashReportManager
  PerformanceReportingManager

If your machine has multiple graphics adapters, Unity may have created a WindowContext on the wrong adapter. If you experience a black screen when playing, please restart the Editor.

(Filename: C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/VR/VRDevice.cpp Line: 179)

The program '[2292] VideoPlayer.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

Comment: Where is the code that is crashing?

Comment: I am using unity 5.6.0 b3 and Video player component to play the video

Comment: Please share your crash log.

Comment: according to unity forum the bug has been fixed in the latest build